# Spring Post Controller not Serializing JSON Request to Java Object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

So I have this controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/zone/settings/ranged/update", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json", consumes="application/json")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> zoneSettingsRangedUpdate(
        WebRequest request,
        @RequestBody RoundRangeData data,
        Map<String, Object> model
) throws IOException {
    model.put("request", data);
    model.put("success",true);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(model, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

With this as the POJO:

```
public class RoundRangeData {
    private BigInteger pricingDate;
    private Long zoneid;
    private Long psid;
    private Float roundTo;
    private Float lowerLimit;
    private Float upperLimit;

public RoundRangeData() {

}

public RoundRangeData(BigInteger pricingDate, Long zoneid, Long psid, Float roundTo, Float lowerLimit, Float upperLimit) {
    this.pricingDate = pricingDate;
    this.zoneid = zoneid;
    this.psid = psid;
    this.roundTo = roundTo;
    this.lowerLimit = lowerLimit;
    this.upperLimit = upperLimit;
}

public BigInteger getPricingDate() {
    return pricingDate;
}

public void setPricingDate(BigInteger pricingDate) {
    this.pricingDate = pricingDate;
}

public Long getZoneid() {
    return zoneid;
}

public void setZoneid(Long zoneId) {
    this.zoneid = zoneId;
}

public Long getPsid() {
    return psid;
}

public void setPsid(Long psid) {
    this.psid = psid;
}

public Float getRoundTo() {
    return roundTo;
}

public void setRoundTo(Float roundTo) {
    this.roundTo = roundTo;
}

public Float getLowerLimit() {
    return lowerLimit;
}

public void setLowerLimit(Float lowerLimit) {
    this.lowerLimit = lowerLimit;
}

public Float getUpperLimit() {
    return upperLimit;
}

public void setUpperLimit(Float upperLimit) {
    this.upperLimit = upperLimit;
}
}
```

Using this request (Chrome devtools screenshot, actual request has quotes around properties):

[image]

And I keep getting this error:

> WARNING:  Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content:  **No serializer found** for class org.springframework.validation.DefaultMessageCodesResolver and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)  (through reference chain: org.springframework.validation.support.BindingAwareModelMap["org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.roundRangeData"]->org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult["messageCodesResolver"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.validation.DefaultMessageCodesResolver and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)  (through reference chain: org.springframework.validation.support.BindingAwareModelMap["org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.roundRangeData"]->org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult["messageCodesResolver"])

What I have tried:

- Changed field accessors to public
- Tried digesting a normal string, same error
- Annotated each getter with @JSONProperty
- Created a unit test and called the controller using generated JSON
  from object mapper from an instance of the RoundRangeData Object

Serializing Java objects into JSON works for responses, but I'm having 
no luck serializing JSON into Java objects in my controllers.

Comment: You can click on tab `View Source` to show the actual payload.

Comment: Do you need the `Map<String, Object> model` bit? Can you try removing it?

Comment: did you configure something on the default `ObjectMapper` or are using using some custom serialization configuration for it? might be something regarding serialization would fail if `FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS` would be set to true

Comment: you need to remove that `model`, I think. The problem if you enable FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS you will get a huge response back which contain a lot f information, which I am pretty sure you do not need.
I would return in the new ResponseEntity something else, like creating your own map, if that is your desire, but I wouldn't use that. I think in order to use that model, you wll need to use @ModelMap or something like that

Comment: Holy crap, @sfat you're a genius, I removed the model from the arguments and it worked. No clue why.

Comment: Glad I could help! I will add an answer with my remarks, if that answers your question

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the attribute `model` from the parameter list. 
The problem if you enable `FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS` for jackson, you will get a huge response back which contain a lot of information, which I am pretty sure you do not need.

I would return in the new ResponseEntity something else, like creating your own map, if that is your desire.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
public class MapSerializer extends JsonSerializer<SpecialMap> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(SpecialMap map, JsonGenerator jgen,
                          SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            jgen.writeStringField(key, map.get(key));
        }
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}


public class SpecialMap extends HashMap<String,String> {
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/zone/settings/ranged/update", method = {RequestMethod.POST}, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> zoneSettingsRangedUpdate(
            @RequestBody RoundRangeData data
    ) throws IOException {

        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(SpecialMap.class, new MapSerializer());
        mapper.registerModule(module);

        String serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(data);
       // return serialized;
        model.put("request", serialized);
        model.put("success",true);

        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(model, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

See the image of successful response.
[image]

Comment: It seems to be working now. Before hand I implemented a class that extended SimpleModule and just registered that, but I followed the general flow of your code snippet and it seems to be working. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You only need to implement Serializble in your pojo

```
public class RoundRangeData implements Serializable {
    //code
}
```